# Error rendering spaces in bold title using ggtext and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtext

I just updated my R to version 4.2. `Ggtext`, which was working fine until then now erase white spaces between words if the text is bold. I found a [very similar question on RStudio forum](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7010) but not a solution for me.

A reproducible example would be as follows (although maybe not that reproducible in other R versions, for it did work fine for me until this morning).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_blank() +
  labs(title = "A title with some words") +
  theme(plot.title = element_textbox_simple(
        face = "bold"))

p
```

[image]

And without `bold`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_blank() +
  labs(title = "A title with some words") +
  theme(plot.title = element_textbox_simple())

p
```

[image]

Comment: That works if I don´t want to use the capabilities of ggtext. I use element_textbox_simple() to automate break lines in long title text (my plots are on a function with variable title lenght).  Or you are suggesting to call ggtext in other place (where?) other then theme()? 
[edit: this was a reply to a removed comment suggesting the use of element_text()]

Comment: I ran in the same issue today and it is actually a known issue (see https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext/issues/83) which could be fixed by installing the development version of `gridtext`.

Comment: Thank yoy @stefan, that worked for me! I scanned the github issues by I guess I did let it pass unseen. Would you be so kind as to post this comment as an answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `**bold text**` to get your text bold:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_blank() +
  labs(title = "**A title with some words**") +
  theme(plot.title = element_textbox_simple())

p
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Sadly this did not produce bold text for me...

Comment: @Arthur, which version did you use of `ggtext`?

Comment: I used version 0.1.1.

Comment: Check this post: https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext/issues/45. Maybe try and set in your `theme` `plot.title=element_markdown()`.

Comment: Thanks again @Quinten, I tried multiple combinations of markdown code \*\*..\*\* or HTML tags <b>...</b> and even CSS (<span style ='font-weight: bold'>...</span>) with element_markdown() and  element_textbox_simple() but was unable to get bold text. Strangely the thomas-neitmann post on the link that you provide does not generate bold text but it does generate color text (that is, the HTML/CSS tags work at least for colors).